# How to define a string literal type as a subtype of another string literal type?

Tags: typescript

How can I create a string literal type as a subtype of another string literal type?

Or in other words, how can I pick values from a string literal type to create a new type?

Example:

```
type Animal = 'goldfish' | 'tuna' | 'elephant'

// I would like to use Pick:
type Fish = Pick<Animal, 'goldfish', 'tuna'>

// So that the desired result is: 'goldfish | 'tuna'
```

However, this doesn't work, because [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) only works when selecting (object) property keys.

Comment: Can you clarify your constraints? You could do it simply as a separate literal like `type Fish = 'goldfish' | 'tuna';`, or as an intersection like `type Fish = Animal & ('goldfish' | 'lion');`.

Comment: I've added the desired result to the question, maybe that wasn't clear.

You're right, I want `type Fish = 'goldfish' | 'tuna';` as the end result, but I want to pick the values from `Animal` to enforce correct values.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than `Pick`, you can [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union). In this case with string literals, it won't get you much further than `&`, though.

```js
type Fish = Extract<Animal, 'goldfish' | 'lion'>   // 'goldfish'
type Fish2 = Animal & ('goldfish' | 'lion')        // 'goldfish'
```

In both of those cases, note that it will not be a compile-time error if you try to pick an entry that is not a part of the original set; it will simply be omitted. With [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) (`extends`) you can can write your own `Subset` type that accomplishes this.

```js
type Subset<K, T extends K> = T;

type Fish3 = Subset<Animal, 'goldfish' | 'lion'>;  // compile error
type Fish4 = Subset<Animal, 'goldfish' | 'tuna'>;  // 'goldfish' | 'tuna'
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDkBzAezQBMAzBAZwAscoAfXYAVzhVoZwjQjCpTmA4AUENCQoAMUpUsUAKIAPYACcUAY2AAeeMnQAaXIRLlq7XGgQE4OAHyjw0KdQBMsnagwAyKAAp8RMmkzHAsrHABKETFoAGUmACMKCC0AaQMAFSgIJQg4YgooFJtZdIBuKIdJaQBmWTjE5O1EDwN-YyD6c0trG3LoquoAFjqEpK13fUMAkxpOnGZWW1KgA)

Comment: Exactly what I need, thanks Jeff.

Out of curiosity, do you know why this is not supported by a built-in utility type? String literal types are popular and intuitively I expect them to work for this as well...

Comment: @rei Glad to help! I don't have a good answer to why this isn't built in, but luckily it's easy enough to write your own. Taking two generic args and returning one unmodified is a little unusual; if I were to guess a proposed alternative it'd be to define the string union without checking, type your call sites as Animal, and let TS enforce at the call site instead of the type definition. Of course, that propagates the error away from the problem/fix, so maybe Subset (or AnimalSet if you made a specific one) is still better in this case, at the cost of one extra line of code to define Subset.