# how do I search this or'd type in the Record definition for a value

Tags: typescript

The typescript docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) define a type to use as keys into a Record<>. I assume this is to limit and lock down the keys that can be used.

```
type CatName = "miffy" | "boris" | "mordred";
```

What kind of type is that? How do I search within it to see if it contains a string value? As in, how do I test it to see if "bart" is one of its "allowed" values?

Using the docs again, suppose the union type above is used as a key in a Record, like this:

```
const cats: Record<CatName, CatInfo> = {}
```

What if, at run time, we receive data on the wire for a different cat name and we try to create a record entry for that different cat name, as in 'bart'? This will generate an error, yes?

Comment: It's a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types). What does 'search within' or 'test' mean in a practical sense? You can't run code against a TS type to 'search' it, but you can construct a new type which extends or is conditional on this one. It would help if you could explain more what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Related, about defining a string literal union that overlaps a known type: [How to define a string literal type as a subtype of another string literal type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67628495/1426891)

Comment: @lawrence-witt I am trying to "trap" the situation where I receive a cat name on the wire (say, in json from an async fetch) that is _not_ included in the `CatName` union type. I added a little more detail to the question.

Comment: @JeffBowman so one option (per above) if I receive a cat name that isn't in the `CatName` type would be to create a new type that adds the new name to `CatName`. That would work but would/could break the binding in (say) the Vue template.

Comment: @lawrence-witt is that really a union type? A union type is the union of 2 (or more) different types, not really the union of a bunch of strings? Or am I reading it too narrowly?

Comment: String literals *are* different types. The same way `string[]` and `number[]` are different types, even though they refer to the same data type (best expressed as `any[]`). As to your edit, TS does not exist at run time so no, using an unexpected string literal with your object won't throw an error. You cannot create types on the fly, they simply express (and enforce in what you write) what you expect will happen. If you have a specific name to add to `CatNames`, write it into your type now; if at runtime you can actually receive any `string` then the existing union is too narrow to be useful.

Comment: It is specifically _because_ TS does not exist at run time that I was looking for a way to check the incoming string/value on the wire in a way that would work at run time. @JeffBowman provides some more detail below and yes, I think my original approach was too narrow to be useful. Not giving up yet, though ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript's types are only for TypeScript compilation; your definitions will not help you check those values at runtime. If you want to do that, you'll need to define the list as an Array or Set.

```js
const CAT_NAMES = ["miffy", "boris", "mordred"] as const;
type CatName2 = typeof CAT_NAMES[number];
```

- `as const` is a [*const assertion*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). You're asserting to Typescript that `CAT_NAMES` will not change, so rather than a simple `string[]` it will type `CAT_NAMES` as `readonly ["miffy", "boris", "mordred"]`.
- `typeof CAT_NAMES[number]` will extract the types of the values of the passed array, which will help you get the `CAT_NAMES` list [without repeating yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

You can then use your `Record` type to define the names as allowed keys. However, you might need to be a little bit careful here: If you've cleverly told TypeScript to assume that these values are part of a short list, then it might be confused and annoyed when you ask it to test that assumption and pass an arbitrary `string`. The same concerns apply if you were to type your wire format type definition to CatName but check their keys/values for arbitrary `string`s instead, though thankfully [`Object.keys` returns `string[]`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12870).

```js
function checkNameWithoutCast(name: string): name is CatName {
  // Error: you've passed the wrong type (string) to `includes`,
  // because `includes` *requires* ("miffy" | "boris" | "mordred")!
  return CAT_NAMES.includes(name);
}

function checkName(name: string): name is CatName {
  // You could also cast to string[], or cast `name` to CatName.
  return (CAT_NAMES as ReadonlyArray<string>).includes(name);
}

function yourFunction(name: string) {
  if (checkName(name)) {  // name is type (string)
    console.log(name);    // name is type ("miffy" | "boris" | "mordred")
  }
}
```

- `name is CatName2` is a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). You could return a `boolean` instead, but by using a type predicate here TypeScript can narrow the type from `string` for you as I have in `yourFunction`.
- `Array.includes(...)` and `Array.indexOf(...) != -1` would work here, but if your list gets long, consider using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and `Set.has` to turn a linear-time O(n) operation into a logarithmic-time O(log n) or constant-time O(1) operation.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsAcnAttAvFARCglgM3xCygB9sAjAewCdcBnE8nWgExolawG4AoXgPQCoAEQj5cAO2gA3OABsArhHpQ4quFBqLJwXGgC0HOKzgV50ODRpwQAOl4BjKpPrBYAQQAqAfUQeAWQBRAGUoTABtHAIiLAAaSloGeOwUNg4uAF01VWdXYD4hUXEpSyhQSCgKdU4oF3KACyp6WQVlegcK6HgkVAgAJnDy8AgqfE9ff2CQiMlFFAoIGky+XnwdRz16xwaIRwBrZDQAdVxgJsVgeDcACkk+gC4oNzpJAHMASif7tCgGWAQR2gAG9eFAoEUgtZaE8QFRFAByGTQMDqFqsRrQADuNBcb2GlRuLykn3KVCgAAMpI4lKwVBS4mCIcJFo44IoWn9JDTFHTVAAqDgAR0UuA49H5UBu0UIxDIiTojHlLBo7E4WA+AEImRxgIoaJIJn5AqE7NTaSo7n0PnwAL78dbcraGnZ7Q59K1oJ7E95fKA-aD-HpAqCg8FFACa8KgzkU8gxCno5LZbjJUp9bwimQ+CVoMfU7gpAYpaeDfQc4N1+sNNxg3mN0xyUAAShATC55CAPNZbAAeDMAPg+Zu5FvonogNt49rWG2dUDh+oAYnPcC4J97gK9SWG-uMbq6DkCJx8PqHw8IA39VF101uSR8meC8kmLHZ5FQ3ifuOCL-6+teBLQNKeCykwCrJMqaSqhkGpMva9pAA)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on what's going on. Your `CatNames as Readonly<string>` approach is kind of what I was looking for. Yes, I can enforce the list of CatNames on the client side and on the API but I hate leaving things to chance. Apologies for the late reply, I got pulled away from this for a bit.